# Wrap/trunc text at 80 column width

Tags: wrapping

Is it possible to wrap text automatically at 80 column length? I mean, writing code or text and then, when I reach 80 characters, put a breakline and continue on the next line (not wrapping the word but putting on the next line).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can customize `fill-column` or do `(setq-default fill-column 80)` in your init file and use `auto-fill-mode`.

You can activate it per mode by using `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)` or with key binding: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c q") 'auto-fill-mode)`. See [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoFillMode) for more.

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you also try `auto-fill-mode`?

Comment: Yes, and it only add spaces when the 80 characters are reached...

Comment: OP: Try starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). If you still see a problem then provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it, saying what you see at each step and what you expected to see. If you do not see a problem, with `emacs -Q`, then recursively bisect your init file to find where you are introducing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for "automatically" (and 5 years ago...) but...

I do it *manually* with the command `fill-paragraph` (`M-Q`). Having `(setq fill-column 80)` in the init file. It even understands some text structure, e.g. that the text is a comment. Which could be good or bad, depending on your needs.